# Existence of bounded continuous $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ st. $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}| \int_{-n}^{n} f(t)\sin(2 \pi n t)dt| = \infty$

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Existence of $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ st. $\displaystyle \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \big| \int_{-n}^{n} f(t)\sin(2 \pi n t)dt \big| = \infty$

I already proved that the space of continuous limited functions $C_b (\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space with $\| f\| = \sup|f|$. But I don't know how to proceed to find this function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Think of Banach and Steinhaus.

Comment: $f(t)=\sin(2\pi t^3)$ looks like a good candidate. We may enforce such kind of "resonance" by imposing that $f(t)$ equals $\sin(2\pi N t)$ over an interval with length $N$, equals $\sin(2\pi(N+1)t)$ over an interval with length $N+1$ and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what could be the collection of linear continuous operators for applying Banach-Steinhaus.

Comment: $I_n(f) = \int_{-n}^n f(t)\sin (2\pi nt)\,dt$

Comment: why is it linear?

Comment: @Alnitak because integration is linear...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_integration